# When calculating the $Q$-value of a reaction, does the energy released by gamma rays need to be considered?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

In certain reaction, gamma rays are released as products. Take the following reaction for example:

$${}^1_{0}n + {}^{235}_{92}U \rightarrow {}^{140}_{54}Xe+{}^{94}_{38}Sr + 2{}^{1}_{0}n + \gamma(6MeV). $$

For determining $Q$-values for reactions, I have been using this equation:

$$Q = [\sum M_{reactants} - \sum M_{products}]c^2.$$

I know that gamma rays do not have any mass/their rest mass is zero. Because of this, my understanding is that the gamma ray can be ignored when calculating the Q-value of this reaction. Is my understanding correct? It feels awkward to ignore it though, since gamma rays have energy and heat (and should make some contribution to the energy of the reaction)

Comment: Energy of products minus energy of reactants. Mass is energy and Vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Fission prompt gammas are part of the value of Q. They are not alone, prompt fission neutrons also possess energy. Then appear with a slight delay, the de-excitation energy of the fission products producing gammas, neutrons and neutrinos.
Here is how the value of Q is distributed for the fission of a 235U nucleus with a thermal neutron:

- kinetic energy of fission products: 169.13 MeV
- prompt neutron energy: 4.92 MeV
- energy of prompt gammas: 6.6 MeV
- delayed neutron energy: 7.40 keV
- delayed gamma energy: 6.33 MeV
- Beta energy: 6.5 MeV
- neutrino energy: 8.75 MeV

TOTAL: 202.23 MeV

Answer (score 1):

The gamma rays are not included in the calculation of the Q value, which represents the energy released in the reaction. However, the emitted gamma rays do contribute in carrying away a fraction of the Q value (the energy released), along with the nonzero kinetic energy of other outgoing particles, as Jean Jacques describes.